# SharePoint search refinements filters PnP-JS-Core 2.0.7

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-search, pnp-js-core

How can I add multiple refinements filters to Sharepoint search, using PnP-JS-Core 2.0.7

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify it as below:

```
$pnp.sp.search({
    Querytext: "Documents",
    RowLimit: 10,
    RefinementFilters : ["and(Author:Gautam,fileExtension:equals('docx'))"]
}).then(function(data){
    console.log(data.PrimarySearchResults);
});
```